# Why is this xclip process killed when I quit Vim?

Tags: process

If I start tmux with no config:

```
$ tmux -Ltest -f/dev/null new
```

then start Vim with no config:

```
$ vim -Nu NONE
```

then from Vim run xclip to write `hello` in the clipboard:

```
:call system('xclip -selection clipboard', 'hello')
```

then quit Vim:

```
:q
```

`hello` is still in the clipboard; `$ xclip -selection clipboard -o` outputs `hello`.

---

If I repeat the same experiment, but start Vim in a tmux split window (experiment 2):

```
$ tmux splitw vim -Nu NONE
```

as soon as I quit Vim, the xclip process is killed and the clipboard is empty.

---

If I repeat the same experiment, but with Nvim (experiment 3), the xclip process is not killed, and the clipboard persist. I had a look at `:h vim-differences` in Nvim's documentation and found this:

```
|system()|, |systemlist()| can run {cmd} directly (without 'shell')
```

This made me think that the issue is due to the fact that Vim starts xclip with a shell, while Nvim starts it without.
To check my hypothesis, I repeated the same experiment, but this time, I wrote `hello` in a file, and started xclip with `job_start()` instead of `system()`, because the former can start a process without a shell (experiment 4):

```
$ echo hello >/tmp/file
$ tmux -Ltest -f/dev/null new
$ tmux splitw vim -Nu NONE
:call job_start('xclip -selection clipboard /tmp/file')
:q
```

And indeed, after quitting Vim, the xclip process is still alive, and the clipboard still contains `hello`.

---

I wanted to understand why the creation of an intermediate shell was an issue.
So, in [experiment 2](https://0x0.st/zu89.txt), before quitting Vim, I checked the ancestors of the xclip process:

```
$ pstree -s -p $(pidof xclip)
systemd(1)---lightdm(951)---lightdm(1126)---upstart(1156)---xclip(15389)
```

Same thing in [experiment 4](https://0x0.st/zu8p.txt):

```
$ pstree -s -p $(pidof xclip)
systemd(1)---lightdm(951)---lightdm(1126)---upstart(1156)---xclip(18541)
```

The tree of processes is identical, and I can't see the intermediate shell created by Vim (maybe because it was killed and xclip was reparented to the upstart process).

So why is xclip killed when I quit Vim in experiment 2, but not when I quit Vim in experiment 4?

---

Edit:

Output of `$ uname -a`:

```
Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-51-generic #55~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 16 09:24:37 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of `$ vim --version | head -n2`:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled May 30 2019 04:42:18)
Included patches: 1-1421
```

Output of `$ tmux -V`:

```
tmux next-3.1
```

Output of `$ zsh --version`:

```
zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```